# isSpike function in SingleCellExperiment package is deprecated?

Tags: r, scrnaseq, bioconductor

I am trying to follow a tutorial from Sanger institute (from May 2019) on analysis of single cell RNA Seq data. They use isSpike function to filter out ERCC (control) and MT (mitochondrial RNA) reads, but I am getting an error message that isSpike is a deprecated function. I am trying to use altExp instead as recommended by some people. I can't seem to figure this out. Can anyone provide some code to use instead of isSpike? I am new to bioinformatics.

I tried to swap out the isSpike function with the altExp function, but I am getting stuck on how to translate the grepl function.

Comment: I think its deprecated.. can you provide an example of your dataset? Sometimes it might have different annotation in yours

Comment: I am following the workshop here [https://scrnaseq-course.cog.sanger.ac.uk/website/index.html].

The github for the course is here [https://github.com/hemberg-lab/scRNA.seq.course].

I pulled the data from here [https://github.com/jdblischak/singleCellSeq] The data files in the tutorial are annotation.txt and molecules.txt which are listed under the Useful files section.

Comment: They hit the code at 01:59:53 in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=thHgPqQpkE4&feature=emb_err_woyt

Answer (score 2):

`isSpike` was provided by `SingleCellExperiment`. It is now deprecated. The notes in `SingleCellExperiment` indicate that one should use `altExps`

I am struggling with a similar problem. Can't compile a package (`powsimR`) because a dependency uses `isSpike` (not used in the code directly), so I have to hunt down where it is used by one of a very long list of dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the latest version of SingleCellExperiment most likely. You should not go back to using the old version. One thing is to check out the [new tutorial](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/SingleCellExperiment/inst/doc/intro.html). In any case, the purpose of altExp() is to provide another slot of ERCC reads and MT.. etc.

So in your example (super not recommended to watch video btw) :

```
molecules = read.delim("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jdblischak/singleCellSeq/master/data/molecules.txt",stringsAsFactors=FALSE,row.names=1)

annotation = read.delim("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jdblischak/singleCellSeq/master/data/annotation.txt",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

We can pull out the spike in and mt genes:

```
library(SingleCellExperiment)
library(EnsDb.Hsapiens.v86)

Spikein_names = grep("^ERCC-",rownames(molecules),value=TRUE)
SpikeIn = molecules[Spikein_names,]

g = genes(EnsDb.Hsapiens.v86)
MTgene_names = g[seqnames(g)=="MT"]$gene_id
MTgenes = molecules[rownames(molecules) %in% MTgene_names,]
```

Have a vector of genes to keep:

```
keep = setdiff(rownames(molecules),c(SpikeIn,MTgenes))
```

Then make the single cell object:

```
sce <- SingleCellExperiment(
assays=list(counts=as.matrix(molecules[keep,])),colData=annotation)
```

Use altExp to slot in the stuff:

```
altExp(sce, "spike-in") <- SummarizedExperiment(SpikeIn)
altExp(sce, "MTgenes") <- SummarizedExperiment(MTgenes)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have everything in a SingleCellExperiment called `sce`, and the old code called for something like this:

```
# old syntax
isSpike(sce, "ERCC") <- grepl("^ERCC", rownames(sce))
```

You can do the following instead:

```
# new syntax
is.spike <- grepl("^ERCC", rownames(sce))
sce <- splitAltExps(sce, ifelse(is.spike, "ERCC", "gene"))
```

This will remove your ERCC counts from the regular counts assay and put them in an 'alternative experiment', calling `sce` will print `altExpNames(1): ERCC`.